# How to compile bootstrap scss to css

Tags: html, css, sass

I've downloaded the [bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) source code but don't want to use all the css in `bootstrap.css` (170kb) nor `bootstrap.min.css` (138kb)

i'm only using button.js (5.09kb) and just want the button related css.

i'm manually able to get all the button related css myself, but it's time consuming to go through the 9000 lines in `bootstrap.css`.

example of some manual css:

```
.btn{color:#00bc8c; border-color:#00bc8c}
.btn:hover,.btn.active{color:#fff; background-color:#00bc8c}
.btn{padding:0.5rem 1rem;font-size:1.171875rem;}
.btn-group{display:inline-flex;}
.btn-group .btn{margin-left:-1px}
.btn-group>.btn:not(:last-child){border-top-right-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}
.btn-group>.btn:not(:first-child){border-top-left-radius:0;border-bottom-left-radius:0}
.btn input[type="radio"]{position:absolute;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);}
```

there's a scss folder in the archive full of all the individual styling sheets

for example, in `_button-group.scss`:

```
.btn-group {
  > .btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  // Reset rounded corners
  > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
  > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn {
    @include border-right-radius(0);
  }
  > .btn:not(:first-child),
  > .btn-group:not(:first-child) > .btn {
    @include border-left-radius(0);
  }
}
```

it's got all the button related stuff i want.

so i tried using http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php but i get this error:

```
Error: no mixin named hover
       Backtrace:
        stdin:16
        on line 16 of stdin
>>     @include hover {
   -------------^
```

the site does state "Enter full url in @import statements if your scss code has those."

so there's more global scss information i need referencing. i assume whoever develops all this bootstrap stuff has a nice program to develop all this scss nicely and organized individually. if anybody knows how i can compile the button scss, please let me know. the only idea i have for "referencing" them myself, is to adding all the other scss to the same source file, but then that'd just compile all that source. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `bootstrap.scss` remove imports that you don't want. (except those you still need)

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "buttons";
@import "button-group";
```

now `bootstrap.css` is just 500 lines of button styling!

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out; }
  @media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .btn {
      transition: none; } }
  .btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    text-decoration: none; }
  .btn:focus, .btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25); }
  .btn.disabled, .btn:disabled {
    opacity: 0.65; }
  .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer; }
  .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
    background-image: none; }

a.btn.disabled,
fieldset:disabled a.btn {
  pointer-events: none; }

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff; }
  .btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0069d9;
    border-color: #0062cc; }
  .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5); }
  .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff; }
  .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0062cc;
    border-color: #005cbf; }
    .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5); }

.btn-secondary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d; }
  .btn-secondary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5a6268;
    border-color: #545b62; }
  .btn-secondary:focus, .btn-secondary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.5); }
  .btn-secondary.disabled, .btn-secondary:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d; }
  .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #545b62;
    border-color: #4e555b; }
    .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.5); }

.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745; }
  .btn-success:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #218838;
    border-color: #1e7e34; }
  .btn-success:focus, .btn-success.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5); }
  .btn-success.disabled, .btn-success:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745; }
  .btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-success.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1e7e34;
    border-color: #1c7430; }
    .btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-success.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5); }

.btn-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  border-color: #17a2b8; }
  .btn-info:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #138496;
    border-color: #117a8b; }
  .btn-info:focus, .btn-info.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.5); }
  .btn-info.disabled, .btn-info:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #17a2b8;
    border-color: #17a2b8; }
  .btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-info.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #117a8b;
    border-color: #10707f; }
    .btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-info.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.5); }

.btn-warning {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  border-color: #ffc107; }
  .btn-warning:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #e0a800;
    border-color: #d39e00; }
  .btn-warning:focus, .btn-warning.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5); }
  .btn-warning.disabled, .btn-warning:disabled {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #ffc107;
    border-color: #ffc107; }
  .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-warning.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #d39e00;
    border-color: #c69500; }
    .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-warning.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5); }

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #dc3545;
  border-color: #dc3545; }
  .btn-danger:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c82333;
    border-color: #bd2130; }
  .btn-danger:focus, .btn-danger.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5); }
  .btn-danger.disabled, .btn-danger:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #dc3545;
    border-color: #dc3545; }
  .btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #bd2130;
    border-color: #b21f2d; }
    .btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5); }

.btn-light {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-color: #f8f9fa; }
  .btn-light:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #e2e6ea;
    border-color: #dae0e5; }
  .btn-light:focus, .btn-light.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.5); }
  .btn-light.disabled, .btn-light:disabled {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: #f8f9fa; }
  .btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-light.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #dae0e5;
    border-color: #d3d9df; }
    .btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-light.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.5); }

.btn-dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-color: #343a40; }
  .btn-dark:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #23272b;
    border-color: #1d2124; }
  .btn-dark:focus, .btn-dark.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5); }
  .btn-dark.disabled, .btn-dark:disabled {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #343a40; }
  .btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-dark.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1d2124;
    border-color: #171a1d; }
    .btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-dark.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-primary {
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #007bff; }
  .btn-outline-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff; }
  .btn-outline-primary:focus, .btn-outline-primary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-primary.disabled, .btn-outline-primary:disabled {
    color: #007bff;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff; }
    .btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-secondary {
  color: #6c757d;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #6c757d; }
  .btn-outline-secondary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d; }
  .btn-outline-secondary:focus, .btn-outline-secondary.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-secondary.disabled, .btn-outline-secondary:disabled {
    color: #6c757d;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-secondary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #6c757d; }
    .btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-secondary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-success {
  color: #28a745;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #28a745; }
  .btn-outline-success:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745; }
  .btn-outline-success:focus, .btn-outline-success.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-success.disabled, .btn-outline-success:disabled {
    color: #28a745;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-success.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #28a745;
    border-color: #28a745; }
    .btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-success.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-info {
  color: #17a2b8;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #17a2b8; }
  .btn-outline-info:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #17a2b8;
    border-color: #17a2b8; }
  .btn-outline-info:focus, .btn-outline-info.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-info.disabled, .btn-outline-info:disabled {
    color: #17a2b8;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-info.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #17a2b8;
    border-color: #17a2b8; }
    .btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-info.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(23, 162, 184, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-warning {
  color: #ffc107;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #ffc107; }
  .btn-outline-warning:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #ffc107;
    border-color: #ffc107; }
  .btn-outline-warning:focus, .btn-outline-warning.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-warning.disabled, .btn-outline-warning:disabled {
    color: #ffc107;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-warning.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #ffc107;
    border-color: #ffc107; }
    .btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-warning.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-danger {
  color: #dc3545;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #dc3545; }
  .btn-outline-danger:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #dc3545;
    border-color: #dc3545; }
  .btn-outline-danger:focus, .btn-outline-danger.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-danger.disabled, .btn-outline-danger:disabled {
    color: #dc3545;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-danger.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #dc3545;
    border-color: #dc3545; }
    .btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-danger.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-light {
  color: #f8f9fa;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #f8f9fa; }
  .btn-outline-light:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: #f8f9fa; }
  .btn-outline-light:focus, .btn-outline-light.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-light.disabled, .btn-outline-light:disabled {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-light.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: #f8f9fa; }
    .btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-light.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(248, 249, 250, 0.5); }

.btn-outline-dark {
  color: #343a40;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: #343a40; }
  .btn-outline-dark:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #343a40; }
  .btn-outline-dark:focus, .btn-outline-dark.focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5); }
  .btn-outline-dark.disabled, .btn-outline-dark:disabled {
    color: #343a40;
    background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-dark.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #343a40; }
    .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .show > .btn-outline-dark.dropdown-toggle:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5); }

.btn-link {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: transparent; }
  .btn-link:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent; }
  .btn-link:focus, .btn-link.focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none; }
  .btn-link:disabled, .btn-link.disabled {
    color: #6c757d;
    pointer-events: none; }

.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg > .btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.3rem; }

.btn-sm, .btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.2rem; }

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; }
  .btn-block + .btn-block {
    margin-top: 0.5rem; }

input[type="submit"].btn-block,
input[type="reset"].btn-block,
input[type="button"].btn-block {
  width: 100%; }

.btn-group,
.btn-group-vertical {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle; }
  .btn-group > .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 1 auto; }
    .btn-group > .btn:hover,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn:hover {
      z-index: 1; }
    .btn-group > .btn:focus, .btn-group > .btn:active, .btn-group > .btn.active,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn:focus,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn:active,
    .btn-group-vertical > .btn.active {
      z-index: 1; }
  .btn-group .btn + .btn,
  .btn-group .btn + .btn-group,
  .btn-group .btn-group + .btn,
  .btn-group .btn-group + .btn-group,
  .btn-group-vertical .btn + .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical .btn + .btn-group,
  .btn-group-vertical .btn-group + .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-left: -1px; }

.btn-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start; }
  .btn-toolbar .input-group {
    width: auto; }

.btn-group > .btn:first-child {
  margin-left: 0; }
.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
.btn-group > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0; }
.btn-group > .btn:not(:first-child),
.btn-group > .btn-group:not(:first-child) > .btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }

.dropdown-toggle-split {
  padding-right: 0.5625rem;
  padding-left: 0.5625rem; }
  .dropdown-toggle-split::after, .dropup .dropdown-toggle-split::after, .dropright .dropdown-toggle-split::after {
    margin-left: 0; }
  .dropleft .dropdown-toggle-split::before {
    margin-right: 0; }

.btn-sm + .dropdown-toggle-split, .btn-group-sm > .btn + .dropdown-toggle-split {
  padding-right: 0.375rem;
  padding-left: 0.375rem; }

.btn-lg + .dropdown-toggle-split, .btn-group-lg > .btn + .dropdown-toggle-split {
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
  padding-left: 0.75rem; }

.btn-group-vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center; }
  .btn-group-vertical .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical .btn-group {
    width: 100%; }
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn + .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn + .btn-group,
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group + .btn,
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0; }
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:not(:last-child) > .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn:not(:first-child),
  .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:not(:first-child) > .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0; }

.btn-group-toggle > .btn,
.btn-group-toggle > .btn-group > .btn {
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  .btn-group-toggle > .btn input[type="radio"],
  .btn-group-toggle > .btn input[type="checkbox"],
  .btn-group-toggle > .btn-group > .btn input[type="radio"],
  .btn-group-toggle > .btn-group > .btn input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    pointer-events: none; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

i used [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) to compile the scss folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked their code on git. - > https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_button-groups.scss

As you can see there are those @include statements - those are mixins that are used and they come from other files.

Also there is a placeholder @extend .btn-xs etc. and you need those so that your scss can be properly translated to css.

You can just find those mixins and placeholders that are used here, or include whole files.